# SQL Error: Cannot Convert 'INT4' to 'BOOL'

Tags: sql, where-clause, data-manipulation

I was able to run the following two SQL statements without any errors:

```
select count("var_1") as c 
from my_table
where "var_1" <> 0;

select count("var_2") as c 
from my_table
where "var_2" <> 0;
```

However, when I try to combine both of these statements together:

```
select count("var_1") as c , count("var_2") as d 
    from my_table
    where "var_1" <> 0 & "var_2" <> 0;
```

This returns the following error:

```
 Cannot Convert 'INT4' to 'BOOL'
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: What database are you using (MySQL, Postgres, MS SQL Server, Oracle, ...)?

Answer (score 2):

Use `case` expressions to do *conditional aggregation*:

```
select sum(case when "var_1" <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) as c,
       sum(case when "var_2" <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) as d 
from my_table
where "var_1" <> 0 or "var_2" <> 0
```

(The where clause isn't required here, but might speed things up.)

Answer (score 1):

Probably order of operations on your SQL implementation, try:

```
select count("var_1") as c , count("var_2") as d 
    from my_table
    where ("var_1" <> 0) & ("var_2" <> 0);
```

Comment: `&` possibly should be `AND` in most DBMS...

Comment: This will not return the same result. You need conditional aggregation. Use case expressions.

Comment: @jarlh This answers why they get `Cannot Convert 'INT4' to 'BOOL'` we can't answer how to get their intended output as they didn't tell us what that is.

Comment: "_when I try to combine both of these statements together_"...

Comment: Anyway, the `&` will probably still cause an error.